# Override theme color* attributes for view or a view hierarchy

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Is there any way to override a theme (activity style) property, such as colorControlActivated, for a particular view or hierarchy of views?

For example, if I have

```
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/my_activated_color<item>
```

in my activity style, would it be possible to override that value in another widget's style, such as a toolbar? Adding a 'colorControlActivated' item doesn't seem to do anything

My current use case is that I have a SwitchCompat in my app bar toolbar, and the global colorControlActivated property I've set for every widget doesn't look well on the toolbar's background. So anything that would help me change that specific color for every view in the toolbar would be great. And hopefully work on both v21 and v15+.

On a slightly unrelated note, could anyone point me to the source code of SwitchCompat, I can't seem to find it in the support library's source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't answer my general question, but does answer my use case scenario, so it might be useful for other people as well.

In order to override the activity's colorAccent (or any other property of the theme), I had to create a ContextThemeWrapper specifically for the switch, and inflate the switch in java, so that I could apply the wrapper.

The code is basically this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
ContextThemeWrapper wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(
        getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(), R.style.CustomTheme);
View.inflate(wrapper, R.layout.toolbar_switch, toolbar);
```